# Schenghen visa enquiry

Tags: paperwork, schengen-visas, applications, spain, uk-residents

I am an 18 year old who has been a UK resident for about 11 years. I just finished my alevels and I am about to 
go to uni. Planning to apply for a Spanish schengen visa for my prospective travel in September. However, I am struggling to provide evidence of my student status as I am yet to receive my results so I am not officialky enrolled. Can I just use my offer letters as proof of my student status?

Comment: Do you yet qualify for British citizenship? If so, obtaining it will make your future international travels much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Just realised i made an error in my post. Actually been a resident for about 7 years. Due to the system and the format of my residency. Have about 10 years to go

Comment: Additionally, I am also struggling to prove financial subsistence. Babysitted all through my time at school so saved up quite a bit for traveling. However i stupidly never opened a bank account until recently so only have about 2 months worth of bank statement and the Spain schengen visa requires 6 months. Was thinking if it it was possible to use a guardians or will it really matter?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details, but as a long term resident, isn't there some form of free movement that applies here? What kind of paperwork do you hold?

Answer (score 2):

No, not according to the Consulate of Spain in London, whose website states the following for required documents:

“Students: Recent, official and signed letter from the UK school / college / university on headed paper stating date of issue, name of the applicant, type of studies, number of lessons (hours) per week and confirming attendance record (a letter of enrolment is not acceptable). The minimum attendance must appear on the letter. “

http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/LONDRES/en/Consulado/Pages/DocumentsRequired.aspx